# Link my custom project with my project in the Azure Portal and send a message to a user

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

I'm going to link my custom project with my project in the azure portal so that i can send a message to a user in Microsoft teams I can't do it it gives me this error :

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException
> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Content type text/html does not have a factory registered to be parsed'
>
> at Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Serialization.ParseNodeFactoryRegistry.GetRootParseNode(String contentType, Stream content)
> at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.d__30.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.d__28.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.d__20`1.MoveNext()   at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.<SendAsync>d__20`1.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.Messages.MessagesRequestBuilder.d__9.MoveNext()
> at Program.d__0.MoveNext()

[I try this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7eeb.png)